# How to get model instance form ModelForm to delete it

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying this:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RmEmplForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        employee = form.save(commit=False)
        employee.delete()
```

but it returns an instance with `None` id field (but there is a correct instance in the table)

```
Employee object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

forms.py

```py
class RmEmplForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Сотрудник",
        queryset = Employee.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = []
```

I would prefer to use `save()` method not to use primary keys or smth else if it's possible

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're explicitly constructing an unsaved Employee, and then trying to delete it. Why? What's the point? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to search for objects out of a very wide queryset (by default `Model.objects.all()`), for deletion or any other action,  then you want Django-filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RmEmplForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        instance.delete()
```

Here I am fetching the instance from [**`cleaned_data`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data).

Answer (score 2):

As your error said `Employee object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.` so first get the pk you want to delete and delete like this:

```
obj = YourModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
     obj.delete()
     return redirect('some_path')
```

Comment: I would prefer to use save() method not to use primary keys or smth else if it's possible. And how can I provide pk parameter to my function?